# ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception [Oracle]

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, triggers

I'm relatively new to Oracle so forgive me for my lack of knowledge. Whenever this trigger is fired I keep getting an error stating that I have an unhandled user-defined exception. Elsewhere in my functions and procedures I have declared and raised my user-defined exactly as this but in this case is doesn't work. I know it's probably something trivial and obvious but as I said I'm fairly new to Oracle so please forgive me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PROGRAMME_BI
BEFORE INSERT ON PROGRAMME
DECLARE
v_run_time programme.run_time%TYPE;
INVALID_DURATION EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
IF v_run_time > 5 THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Program duration is valid');
  COMMIT;
ELSE
  RAISE INVALID_DURATION;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN INVALID_DURATION THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Program duration is not long enough');
  ROLLBACK WORK;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE||SQLERRM);
END;
```

**UPDATE**
I have updated the line after the exception is raised so it doesn't give me the unhandled user-defined exception error anymore. However it still does not work as intended. Whenever I enter in a program duration greater than 5 I get the following in the DBMS output window.

```
-20001ORA-20001: Program duration is not long enough
ORA-06512: at "DT2113A.PROGRAMME_BI", line 13
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DT2113A.PROGRAMME_BI'
Program not added
```

Comment: Apologies! As I said I'm new to the whole thing! I thought MySQL was the language and Oracle was the program. Can you help me with my problem?

Comment: MySQL is an open source DBMS owned by the company Oracle. The term "Oracle" usually refers to the DBMS named "Oracle" and the language that is used in stored procedures and triggers in Oracle is PL/SQL

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying! I notice on your profile that you're quite knowledgeable on the subject so I would really appreciate your help with this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to assign value to v_run_time Kindly try the below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PROGRAMME_BI
BEFORE INSERT ON PROGRAMME
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_run_time programme.run_time%TYPE:=:new.run_time;
INVALID_DURATION EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
 IF v_run_time > 5 THEN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Program duration is valid');
  COMMIT;
ELSE
RAISE INVALID_DURATION;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN INVALID_DURATION THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Program duration is not long enough');
  ROLLBACK WORK;
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE||SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and I got this error: Error: ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers